# Generate Custom Enum using NSWag cli

Tags: enums, swagger, nswag

I have the following enum in c#

```cs
    public enum ErrorCodes: int {
        [Display(Name = "Nothing", Order = 1)]
        None = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Already Exists", Order = 2)]
        AlreadyExists = 1,
        ...
        [Display(Name = "Teapot", Order = 99)]
        Teapot = int.MaxValue
    }
```

that generates the following swagger for the enum:

```json
"ErrorCodes": {
  "enum": [
    0,
    1,
    ...
    2147483647
  ],
  "x-enumNames": [ 
    "None",
    "AlreadyExists"
    ...
    "Teapot"
  ],
  "x-enumDisplayNames]: [
    "Nothing",
    "Already Exists"
    ...
    "Teapot"
  ]
}
```

When I the nswag cli for the file it generates:

```cs
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "14.0.3.0 (NJsonSchema v11.0.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
    public enum ErrorCodes
    {

        None = 0,

        AlreadyExists = 1,

        Teapot = 2147483647,

    }
```

The swagger UI UI displays the integer value, not the string and the client does not handle the display name (as expected).

Using the nswag cli, how can I have it process the enum and generate it with the DisplayAttribute?